# CSS works for id, but not for class because of bootstrap

Tags: html, css

i got following problem:

`<input id="c-search" type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search..."/>`

```
.search {
    width: 275px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

the width of my css doesn't work because it's overriden by the **form-control**-class from bootstrap.

i can't use **!important** in css, because i need to change the width with javascript later and i don't want to align the css for the id, because i got multiple objects from class search (and i have to select elements by id later too).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Class selector should be `.search`, not `search`.

Comment: @technophyle sorry, tipping error. the width is the only thing gets overriden, so the rest works fine.

Comment: Change className `.search` to something else and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining multiple class selectors raises the importance of the rules.

What should help:

```
.form-control.search {
...
}
```

You can also add `input` to the mix:

```
input.form-control.search {
...
}
```

If that doesn't help, you can keep on chaining .search (which you shouldn't generally do but Bootstrap sometimes requires that):

```
input.form-control.search.search.search {
...
}
```

CSS uses something called "specifity" to determine the importance of your rules. In simpler terms: `style=` is worth 1000, ID is worth 100, attributes/classes/pseudoselectors are worth 10 and tag selectors are worth 1. (It's much more complex than this, but this is generally a good rule of thumb for CSS specifity.)

Answer (score 0):

How is bootstrap overriding you? The answer is likely selector specificity, which means it has a higher priority than your selector. But you can use the same trick and write a selector with a higher specificity than it. For the sake of demonstration:

```
 .search.search.search.search.search{ ... }
```

now has a specificity of 0 0 5 0 instead of 0 0 1 0. The first number is inline styles (i.e. style="..."), the second is id's (i.e. id=""), the third is class, and the fourth is element (i.e. div).

When your browser decides which CSS rule(s) to apply, if two rules conflict, it uses the one with *more specificity*. So an ID selector will always beat a class selector, for instance.

If you inspect the element in question and look at what other selectors are applying rules to it, you can figure out how much specificity you need to overrule it.

[More about specificity](http://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca)